# System.Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-3.0, assemblies

let us consider im having an application AAA. From my application im loaded an assembly named as BBB.When im in BBB path, i need to get the AAA Assembly name at run time.
how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

will return the assembly it's written in (the currently executing assembly). Or in your case, maybe you'll need:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
```

to get the executable assembly (the assembly that the application was started with).